# Suppose $k$ is even and $4 \nmid k$, please explain why $k/2$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Assume integer $k$ is even and $k>2$. In order for $k/2$ to be odd, $k$ cannot be divisible by $4$. Can someone please explain why this is true, or point me in the right direction? I don't need to prove it for what I'm working on, but it came up as a fact in something else I'm trying to prove, and I just can't find anything on it (and I dislike using things I can't prove or understand). Thanks.

Comment: @Apurv: 22 is not divisible by 4, and thus 22/2 is odd. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: If we know for an integer $k$ that $k/2$ is even, it must be divisible by $4$ as $k/2=2m$ hence $k=4m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an even integer is not divisible by $4$, it means that if doesn't have enough two's to cancel out the two two's present in $4$. Which means it has only one two. Which means it you take away the last of the twos remaining in the number, you get all odd factors, and product of odd factors is odd. Hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @Bob. If you think the answer cleared your doubt, accept it by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 3):

If $4 \nmid k$, then $k = 4n+1$ or $4n+2$ or $4n+3$, where $n$ is an integer. You may observe that if $k$ is even, then $k$ have to be of the form $4n+2$. Then $\frac{k}{2} = 2n+1$, which is odd.

Comment: Ahh. That does make sense. Thank you very much! I think the way you wrote it finally made a few connections appear. This is probably something I was supposed to remember or infer from past lessons in modulo/modular arithmetic, and that just didn't occur to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D_n$ denote the number of times that $2$ appears in the prime factorization of $n$:

- $2 \mid  k \implies D_k \geq 1$
- $4 \nmid k \implies D_k <    2$
- $1 \leq D_k < 2 \implies D_k = 1$
- $D_k = 1 \implies D_{k/2} = 0 \implies k/2$ is odd